# CasperJS Click Not Working on Anchor without href

Tags: jquery, phantomjs, casperjs

I am totally new to CasperJS. I am trying to simulate a "click" on an anchor on a page which does not have a href attribute. The page uses jquery to bind a javascript function to call when a click on this element occurs. It works if I run it manually through a browser, but, trying to simulate this using click() or thenClick() does not work. Here's a simplified page to demonstrate the problem I am facing:

one.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>One.html Page</title>
  <meta charset=”utf-8”>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">    
    <div>
      <h3>Test</h3>
    </div>

    <div>
        <a id="enterButton" name="enterButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Enter</a>
    </div>

  </div>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.0.min.js"></script>

  <script>

  $("#enterButton").click(validateOne);
  function validateOne() {
    window.location.href = "pageTwo.html";
  }

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

my casper.js test script:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('urlTo/one.html', function() {
  this.echo(this.getTitle());
});

casper.then(function() {
  this.click('#enterButton');
});

casper.wait(200, function() {
  this.capture('pageTwo.png');
});

casper.run();
```

When I run my casper.js script, the screen I captured is still the initial page (one.html), instead of pageTwo.html. I have tried several things, but, it seems the problem is the "click" event is not being triggered. I confirmed that if I add a href to the anchor tag in the html to invoke the javascript function, things will work fine. But, I cannot change the implementation of the html to make my test script works. I think there should be a way to get this work within casperJS. Hoping for some experienced user here to shed some light on this.

Thank you!

Comment: I have found the cause of the problem. The problem is that the jquery library is not getting included. Thus, logic involving jquery are not working. When I use a jquery.min.js that is on my server, it works fine. ...In summary, the problem I was facing is because the jquery click event was not getting tied to the anchor. Thus, nothing happens when casperJS clicks on that anchor.

Comment: Now, what if I cannot change the code to use a local version of the jquery library...what should be my casperjs script be to properly load jquery library to the DOM for the above HTML to work as-is?

Comment: You can read how to include jQuery to your web page here: http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/faq.html#can-i-use-jquery-with-casperjs

Comment: Also I suggest you use xpath to click elements, it's the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact issue when scraping a site. What fixed it for me was changing the viewport casper.create() to

`viewportSize: {
          width: 1920,
          height: 1080
        }`

and using the `casper.viewport(1920, 1080)` function in a then step.

The page I was trying to scrape was a single page application that required me to use CasperJS to click a link to view the next page. I am thinking for whatever reason the next page was not being loaded due to the small default viewport size of 400x300 There might a more efficient way of doing this but this worked for me.